# Selecting with JQUERY a dynamically inserted Div element with a .on('change') event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an `.on('change')` event to a Select which is part of a dynamically inserted row. The `console.log(data);` is returning the correct data set. I cannot figure out how to have it select the `#prototypePrice` on the same row that the select was activated.

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#lineitems').on('change', '.prototypeSelect', function() {  
        var that = $(this); 
    $.get('getItem.php?q=' + $(this).val(), function(data) { 
        console.log(data);      
        var objItem = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  
        that.closest('#prototypePrice').val(objItem.item_price); //this is wrong

      });
   });
});
```

Here is the Prototype Row:

```
 <div style="display:none;" id="rowPrototype" >                                     
 <div>
      <select id="prototypeSelect" class="prototypeSelect">

     //Select Options

      </select>
 </div>
 <div>
    <input type="text" id="prototypePrice" class="prototypePrice">
    </input>
    </div>
 </div
```

Here is the JQUERY to insert the prototype row:

```
 var objLineitem;       
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.invoiceClass').click(function() {
    $.get('getlineItems.php?q=' + $(this).attr("name") , function(data) {

         console.log(data);     

    var objLineitem = $.parseJSON(data);

    for (i=0; i < objLineitem.length; i++) {

    var newRow = $('#rowPrototype').clone();
    newRow.show();
    $('#lineitems').append(newRow);
    newRow.attr('id', 'insertedRow');
    newRow.attr('class', 'row insertedPrototypeRow');
```

Comment: make a working fiddle with some options, it will be easy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the child of the next sibling of the changed select, so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lineitems').on('change', '.prototypeSelect', function () {
        var that = $(this);
        $.get('getItem.php?q=' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var objItem = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            that.parent().next().find('.prototypePrice').val(objItem.item_price); //this is wrong
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gsDJE/)

Also note that, if the given structure is repeated then you should not use `id` for those elements since it will create duplicate ids

Also, `input` is a self closing element so there is no `</input>`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. The Fiddle is useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

`closest` traverse up the DOM tree and get the first matched ancestor.

In your case, the input that you want to set the value is the child of a div which is the next immediate sibling of parent div of `that`

So you can use:

```
that.closest('div').next().find('.prototypePrice').val(objItem.item_price);
```

instead of:

```
that.closest('#prototypePrice').val(objItem.item_price);
```

Check: [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) , [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) , [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use unique id for each row. Then it will be easier  to search using that id

`$('#'+rowID + " .prototypePrice").val(newValue)`

or

you can use row context

```
$(".prototypePrice",that.parents('#rowPrototype')).val(newVal)
```

Agree with arun if 'prototypePrice' is repeating then dont use it as id.Also rowPrototype. it shud be used as class

```
$(".prototypePrice",that.parents('.rowPrototype')).val(newVal)
```